# How to add columns in select list SQL which are rows of other table : SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I need help. I have a table from where I'm pulling **Max** data group by **ID** like below.

```
select ID, max(basic) as B, max(hra) as H
from #temp
group by ID
```

I have another table (only one column) where I have certain values. Number of rows or data of this table is dynamic. X and Y are just random data. There could be many rows with any *varchar* data.

```
select * from #dummy
```

Now I need rows of #dummy table as columns of #temp like below.

[image]

Earlier I was thinking of pivoting but it won't work as there is no relation between these two tables. Any help, TIA.

Comment: You want the column values from table2 to become column names?

Comment: If there is no relation, how are the rows connected?

Comment: I'll add data on new columns by other logic... yes to @jarlh and I know you can help it..

Comment: Something does not make sense.  You asked to add a column that has no relationship to the current result set?  Isn't that a bit like an auto parts distributor selling spark plugs for a Ferrari but the person needs them for a Volkswagen?

Comment: @Leptonator .. yeah it has no direct sense.. but for one business requirement I have do something like that.. I'm close and this is just last part I need to do..

Comment: And will the values for those columns be empty in each row, as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: is the values in second table fixed or will be dynamic? i mean will it be always X and Y.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using static sql.

Comment: @RichardIrons .. they will be blank like shown... I'll add data to them later.. and **Akhil Kumar** ... dynamic..

Comment: Wait, you'll add data later? Where? Those cells don't represent any storage location in the database. Are you going to be loading the whole result up into excel or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a query like this you can create a "column list" with empty entries and create a dynamic SQL Statement. This you execute with `EXEC`:

```
DECLARE @addColumns VARCHAR(MAX)=
    (
        SELECT ','''' AS ' + Name
        FROM #dummy
        FOR XML PATH('')
    );

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT ID, MAX(basic) as B, MAX(hra) as H ' + @addColumns + ' FROM #temp group by ID;'

EXEC (@cmd);
```

btw: The statement created will look like this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(basic) as B, MAX(hra) as H ,'' AS x,'' AS y FROM #temp group by ID;
```

EDIT2: If you want to add these columns to some table permanently (to add data later) you could use the same approach:

```
DECLARE @addColumns VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(  (
        SELECT ',' + Name + ' VARCHAR(100) NULL'
        FROM @dummy
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'');

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD ' + @addColumns +';'
```

The statement would look like:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD x VARCHAR(100) NULL,y VARCHAR(100) NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped .. I know what I'm doing is not 100% logical but I've to do it because of old system architecture and new business requirement. Thanks buddy!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

this request is sick but i think cursor can do something with it.

```
 DECLARE @SQLString varchar(100),@new_column varchar(10)
 DECLARE dummy_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name FROM dummy
  OPEN dummy_cursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM dummy_cursor into @new_column
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @SQLString =
 N'Alter TABLE temp ADD @new_column varchar(10)'
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
FETCH NEXT FROM dummy_cursor
END
CLOSE dummy_cursor
DEALLOCATE dummy_cursor
```

Comment: CURSORs are evil and should be avoided where ever possible. They are row based / procedural thinking and almost ever to be replaced by better (set based) approaches...